# Add static text when table breaks to another page

Tags: jasper-reports, break

I'm using *iReport 5.1*.

I have a table that occupies more than one page and what I want is to add the text *'Continuation'* when the table breaks to the next page. Is it possible? Can someone tell me how?

Here is the code for my table:

```xml
 <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="6c415069-464e-4992-9985-60fc8a7a211b" key="table" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="5" y="43" width="550" height="20"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="BaseWarrantiesDataset" uuid="f57b0a82-17a2-4830-9bd9-eaa5956dbef8">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{baseWarranties}.getWarranties())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="190" uuid="c8ed3403-1a70-4ac8-a8fa-90b5c211eed8">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="19" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3">
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="47754cda-9f4e-480f-bf83-efc3443366dd" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="184" height="19" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="a6310eb0-ff7f-46e8-9f4d-c40df676d54c">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="19" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3">
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="49eb2945-26c1-4b71-9bcb-35a019aba931" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="84" height="19" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainPlanValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="0215fd2f-56a7-4495-9737-8cff412615f0">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="19" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3">
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="99c38f4d-b53b-4425-a1c1-500769284917" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="84" height="19" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{counterPlanValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="4c739247-666b-4edd-916d-638365c40dc7">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="19" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3">
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="51dd141f-bbba-4e81-bde1-1cb050ef3ec6" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="84" height="19" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{starPlanValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="4809f6dd-c363-42d6-b362-ba4974ef8691">
                        <jr:detailCell height="19" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3">
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="48d6d0da-ba64-4d79-9053-aeabfc6dbee6" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="84" height="19" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{objects}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="98a3761e-0c14-43b7-88e3-4a7f3768cc22" mode="Opaque" x="5" y="22" width="550" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{baseWarranties}.getLabel()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="9074f691-90ed-49ac-ab79-3f76ace8c479" x="294" y="3" width="89" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{counterPlanName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="86697461-d573-4e90-9674-5e43e2cd66b9" x="202" y="3" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainPlanName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="0f08e70d-dfc1-421f-96e7-4cab12061c97" x="383" y="3" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{starPlanName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: What can I say? It's a simple table made through a java.util.List. I have no idea how to implement this. I don't even know if it's possible to do it. If it helps, I updated the question with the table code.

Comment: Well the point is, the figgure out about its possible or not, check how it works. If you know how it works, and have produced after doing resaearch at least some test code and it is not running anyway THEN reformat your question and ask not before here on SO, because otherwise your Question will be Off-Topic